# Python recursing through directories, looking for certain file - fastest method?

Tags: python

I have hundreds of common files in hundreds of directories of which I'm appending to a list.  With that I'm wanting to know the fastest python method to recurse through directory + x number of sub-directories looking for certain file:

I've recorded time elapse for 50 mock tests for each method below.  There does not seem to be much of a significant difference between the two (method 1 on average about 0.2 seconds faster):

**Method 1:**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputDir):
    for f in files:
        if f == fileName + '.xyz':
```

**Method 2:**

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputDir):
    for f in [x for x in files if x == fileName + '.xyz']:
```

Are there any faster methods out there for this?

Thank you!

Comment: why are you adding `'.xyz'`?

Comment: fileName variable is defined by a user parameter without the extension of which I did not show.  It is the file that I'm looking to append to the final list.

Comment: Don't do `filename + '.xyz'`evertytime. Instead, assign it once `myname = filename + '.xyz'` and then `if myname in files`. Its a faster compare and since the filename can't be in the list more than once, you don't have to keep comparing once its found.

Comment: Good point, but will that really speed things up?

Comment: yes, kinda. The disk read is likely the slowest part, but if you have a lot of files or a deep tree, it'll be a measurable difference. If you've got a few hundred files, then it makes no difference.

Comment: if after `if f == fileName + '.xyz'` you stop the cycle by `break` it will faster otherwise they are the same ... just syntactic  sugar.

Comment: depending on how many files you are handling and how often those change it might be useful to build a lookup-cache, either via redis if you've got a lot of files, or a simple defaultdict(list) with the name of the file as the key and a list of paths.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```py
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputDir):
    for f in [x for x in files if x == fileName + '.xyz']:
```

Use this:

```py
filename = 'file.xyz'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(inputDir):
    if(filename in files):
        print("File found!")
```